# C# find all user controls starting with a certain string

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

I am wanting to dynamically load user controls onto a webpage for a particular group. However, I do not want to (but I think I have to) code to load each one onto the webpage. Is there a way for me to loop through the ascx files within the VS project and find all of the files that begin with "list" and load them onto the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Direcrtory Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Directory_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) to find your files. Choose method based on if you need subdirectories as well, certain methods allow you to only include ones that match search pattern. Then just LoadControl the strings(most of these methods output string[]) you want

Comment: I never thought about using the Directory Class. So since this will be a web application I would have to use virtual paths or application path?

Comment: VirtualPath to use in LoadControl